# Sending Message: undefined ID

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-native

I am trying to create a simple independent chat. I used Firebase to make a database and imported the reference on `Fire.js`.

However, whenever I try to send a message on the Chat screen an error pops up saying:

`Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'messages.user._id`

This is the code from my `Chat.js` :

```
import React from 'react';
import {Platform, KeyboardAvoidingView, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import {GiftedChat} from 'react-native-gifted-chat';
import Fire from '../Fire';

export default class ChatScreen extends React.Component {
state ={
    messages: []
}

get user() {
    return{
        _id: Fire.uid,
        name: this.props.navigation.state.params.name
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    Fire.get(message => 
        this.setState(previous => ({
            messages: GiftedChat.append(previous.messages, message)
        }))
    );
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    Fire.off();
}

  render(){
  const chat = <GiftedChat messages={this.state.messages} onSend={Fire.send} user={this.user}/>;
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
        return( 
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{flex:1}} behavior='padding' keyboardVerticalOffset={30} enabled>
                {chat}
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }

  return <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>{chat}</SafeAreaView>

  }
}
```

And this is the code from my `Fire.js`:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

class Fire{
constructor() {
    this.init()
    this.checkAuth()
}

init = () => {
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
        firebase.initializeApp({

                //This is the reference to the Firebase data

        });
    }
};

checkAuth = () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (!user) {
            firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
        }
    });
};

send = messages => {
    messages.forEach(item => {
        const message = {
            text: item.text,
            timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
            user: item.user
        };

        this.db.push(message);
    });
};

parse = message => {
    const {user, text, timestamp} = message.val();
    const {key: _id} = message;
    const createdAt = new Date(timestamp);

    return {
        _id,
        createdAt,
        text,
        user
    };
};

get = callback => {
    this.db.on("child_added", snapshot => callback(this.parse(snapshot)));
};

off() {
    this.db.off()
}

get db() {
    return firebase.database().ref("messages");
}

get uid() {
    return (firebase.auth().currentUser || {}).uid;
}
}

export default new Fire();
```

I don't understand why this is happening. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The error message:

> Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'messages.user._id

Is telling you that your code that invokes push():

```
        const message = {
            text: item.text,
            timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
            user: item.user
        };

        this.db.push(message);
```

is passing an object that contains undefined in `message.user._id`.  Since we can't see what's in `item.user`, we can't diagnose this for you, so you will need to figure out why this is happening.

The bottom line is that the Firebase SDK won't let you write objects whose properties contain undefined, and you need to check for that in your code.